# Controlling HTML elements dependent on geo IP

Tags: geolocation, geoip

We have a mobile web page [here](http://spiritdigital.co.uk/outpost/mobile/index.html) which will be available in different countries and within each country we need the ability to change the following based on the visitor's IP:

- div#container to have a different backround image
- div#buttons to be hidden and div#buttons-2 to be shown

Using JavaScript called [GeoIP](http://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/javascript) we are so far able to identify the visitor's country and grab the function name in the form of a two character ISO 3166-1 to be used to control the other JavaScript functions.  For example, I am from the UK and so when I visit the page the JavaScript generates this code:

```
function geoip_country_code() { return 'GB'; }
```

In the HTML there is currently a script which says:

```
    if (geoip_country_code() == 'GB') 
    {
      alert("Hello, you are in Great Britain");
    }
```

We want to develop that so that we can manipulate the CSS of specified elements but we're not well versed in JavaScript so this is where we need help.

This is the JavaScript embedded into the page:

```
<script src="http://j.maxmind.com/app/country.js" charset="ISO-8859-1"></script>
```

Here are the HTML elements we want to control:

```
<div id="container">
            <div id="buttons">
                <a href="#" target="blank">
                    <div class="button youtube"></div>
                </a>
                <a href="#" target="blank">
                    <div class="button facebook"></div>
                </a>
                <a href="#" target="blank">
                    <div class="button web"></div>
                </a>
                <a href="#" target="blank">
                    <div class="button appstore"></div>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: I am not well versed at all in JavaScript so I am fumbling through some attempts now.  All I have tried is to test if it the JS is working via the following:

if (geoip_country_code() == 'GB') 
 {
   alert("Hello, you are in Great Britain");
 }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var map = {
    'GB': {
        'background': 'img1.jpg',
        'buttons': 'show',
        'buttons2': 'hide'
    }
};

var country = geoip_country_code();
$('#container').css('background', map[country].background);
$('#buttons')[map[country].buttons]();
$('#buttons2')[map[country].buttons2]();
```

This is an example using jQuery. I hope you get the idea of using a "mapping object" (with only UK there, but add countries as you wish), and then you can do your actions based on this.

Comment: Great, thank you so much. Very helpful to understand this concept of maps. Can I change the href of an <a> element in this way?

Comment: I have tried to use this code:     `'href': 'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=12345678'` and `$("a.youtube").attr('href', map[country].href);` but I get `uncaught syntaxerror unexpected string` when it reads the YouTube link. Any ideas?

Comment: Hm no sorry I don't see the problem :/ Could you make a jsfiddle?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the country code returned, you should change the stylesheets(css)

like if returned GB then load the css where
    div#container have a different backround image
    div#buttons be hidden and div#buttons-2 be shown

else vice-versa.

or you can simply do this with javascript

Make a function which :
sets the background image of container,
hide div#button,
show div#buttons-2

and another function to do vice versa like :
sets another background image of container,
show div#button,
hide div#buttons-2

Now you can call the appropriate function for which to show like :
if returned 'US' call func1,
if returned 'UK' call func2